# Fast way to compute a truncated series using Fold

Tags: performance-tuning, recursion, functional-style, timing

I'm looking at an efficient and fast way to compute the results of a finite summation

$$\sum_{i=0}^Mf_ig_i\,. $$

I noticed that simply applying

```
Expand/@Sum[f[i]Expand/@g[i],{i,0,M}]
```

is not very efficient time-wise. The function f is generated recursively for any integer argument. I already use memoization when computing the functions recursively. They look like this

```
g[0] = 1;
g[n_] := g[n] = Expand@Sum[2^s, {s, 0, n - 1}];
```

Where do you think is the most consuming part?

```
f[0] = 1;
f[1] = Sum[Gamma[n] \[Alpha]^n, {n, 1, M}] + O[\[Alpha]]^(M + 1);
f[n_] := f[n] = (f[n - 1] + O[\[Alpha]]^M) (f[1] + O[\[Alpha]]^M)
```

- The evaluation of the functions f and g?
  Is there a way to save the value is an efficient way? A noticed that writing the values into a list (creating "fList" and "gList") using Table is also very timeconsuming.
- Using the function Sum? Would using Fold and pure functions be more efficient? (I tried but I didn't manage to write this sum using pure functions into the Fold function....)

Comment: Regarding the first point, do you know about [memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html.en)?  If your functions are recursive, this is likely to help greatly.

Comment: @jjc385 Oupsy, I forgot to mention that I already used memoization in the recursive computation. Thanks for noticing, I will edit the question.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example?  It's hard (for me, at least) to say much without one.

Comment: @jjc385 I made it more detailed? Does it seem to be more clear now?

Comment: The definition for `g` currently is not recursive. Is it missing something?

Comment: @jjc385 Clumsy copy-paste-adapt, thanks. No g is not recursive, indeed, only f. (I will clarify that too.)

Comment: What sort of `M`s are you using?

Comment: For the moment this code works ok for M up to 25. I need to go to M=100.

Comment: fyi g is just `2^n-1`  (not a huge timing difference to use that though. )  This runs fast enough for me at `M=100` What timing are you getting?

Comment: I think problem might be in definition of `f[1]`. If you define it before defining numerical value of `M`, then *Mathematica* will evaluate `Sum` from RHS of `f[1]` definition to a general `DifferenceRoot` expression, which will be evaluated in each non-memoized call to `f` function, making them terribly slow. If you define `f[1]` after defining `M`, then `f[1]` will be ordinary `SeriesData` expression and evaluation will be much faster. It would be best to avoid global variable in function definition and use `m` as second argument of `f`.

Comment: Isn't `f[n]` just `f[1]^n`, since `f[1]` is `O[alpha^(M+1)]`?  But I think jkuczm hit the nail on the head -- the `M=100` case runs in well under a second as long as `M` is set before `f` is defined.  (Be sure to `ClearAll[f]` to erase any old definitions.)

Comment: FYI when I said it ran fast enough I set `M=number` before everything else.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `f[1]` uses [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set) instead of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed), which means that `f[1]` evaluates using whatever the current value of `M` is. If `M` is not defined, you will get a [`DifferenceRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot) object:

```
Clear[M]
f[1] = Sum[Gamma[n] α^n, {n, 1, M}] + O[α]^(M + 1)

(*
α^(1 + M) SeriesData[α, 0, {}, 0, 0, 1] + 
 DifferenceRoot[
   Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {\[FormalN] α \[FormalY][\
\[FormalN]] + (-1 - \[FormalN] α) \[FormalY][
         1 + \[FormalN]] + \[FormalY][2 + \[FormalN]] == 0, \[FormalY][1] == 
      0, \[FormalY][2] == α}]][1 + M]
*)
```

Having `f[1]` defined as a [`DifferenceRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot) object will slow things down.

Now, if you want to evaluate the sum for different values of `M`, you will want to clear the memoized values. I think the easiest way to do this is to use the `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` the function, so that all memoized values are automatically erased when the [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block) finishes. You will also want to [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block) `M` to the desired value first. First, here is your definition of `g` and a revised definition of `f`:

```
g[0] = 1;
g[n_] := g[n] = Expand@Sum[2^s,{s,0,n-1}];

f[0] = 1;
f[1] := Sum[Gamma[n] α^n, {n,1,M}] + O[α]^(M+1);
f[n_] := f[n] = (f[n-1]+O[α]^M) (f[1]+O[α]^M)
```

Then, your desired computation:

```
res[m_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{M = m, f, g},
    Sum[g[i] f[i], {i, M}]
]
```

Test:

```
res[5] //TeXForm
```

> $\alpha +4 \alpha ^2+15 \alpha ^3+57 \alpha ^4+226 \alpha ^5+O\left(\alpha ^6\right)$

```
res[100]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.025141, Null}